# Create twitter style icons

Tags: css, twitter

Are there any tutorials on how to create Twitter style icons which change when hovered over, I'm looking specifically for how to create something like the "Favourite" "Reply" and "Retweet" icons. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Adobe photoshop tutorial in creating some very sleek and glossy professional twitter icons [PS twitter icon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaNTZyne5RY)
then use css to set the hover icon the pushed icon 
 you can use simple twitter icon and use PS to make some modification like outer glow , drop shadaw and more other things

Comment: @anonyplng - Thanks alot!